# How to check whether a file contains "." (dot) operator

Tags: laravel

I have a code which asks user to upload a file. The file may be audio or image or anything. I asks user to enter file name. If he Enter file name my code adds extension to it. It is working fine. But if user enters extension say audio.mp3 then it saves as `audio.mp3.mp3`. So I have to check if user entered name contains dot then it should not take extension.
I used pregmatch but it is not working.

My code

```
  $splitOptions = explode(',',$request->input('mediaName'));
$fileExtension = pathinfo($file[$i]->getClientOriginalName(),PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$checkExtension =  explode('.',$request->input('mediaName'));
if(preg_match("/[.]/", $checkExtension)){
         $mediaName =  $splitOptions[$i];
}
else
{
     $mediaName =  $splitOptions[$i]."_$fileExtension";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use laravel helper

```
$value = str_contains('This is my name', 'my');
// true
```

Comment: That is not working.It says first parameter should be string,. but I pass file to there.